# Python subprocess open command prompt in new window as administrator and execute command

Tags: python, subprocess, command-prompt

I have the following code, where I am trying to open command prompt in a separate window as administrator and want to execute a command. I am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://www.xingyulei.com/post/py-admin/index.html) here, but it says:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified in the Terminal.

Here is the code, I am trying. If I just run this command `cmd.exe /K "EchoServer.exe -c -s"` it runs fine but won't run as admin.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

def OpenServers():
    print("Full path "+echoServerFullPath)
    print(os.path.exists(echoServerFullPath))
    os.chdir(echoServerFullPath)
    command = ['cmd.exe /K "CoreServer.exe -c -s"', '/c', 'runas', '/user:administrator']
    #cmd.exe /K "EchoServer.exe -c -s"
    cmd1=subprocess.Popen(command,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

[image: error]

Just a quick edit, when I try

```
subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/user:Administrator', '"CoreServer.exe -c -s"'],creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

It opens command prompt and says enter password for administrator.

Comment: If software running as a less-privileged user could escalate privileges without the human operator having to do something (like enter a password) to approve it, all malware would use that technique and there'd be no security benefit (in terms of preventing malicious software from using machine-level privileges) to running as a non-admin user.